# CSS Jitter no menu Hover

Tags: css, menu

Programei um menu com 2 hovers (class), um que faz o texto subir e outro que faz o texto ficar bold.

Mas quando coloco o mouse sobre as palavras as outras do lado se movem, isso é conhecido como CSS Jitter, mas não estou conseguindo arrumar isto.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
   <ul>
     <li id="agenda-link"><a class="float" class="scroll" href="#agenda">Agenda</a></li>
     <li id="musicas-link"><a class="float" class="scroll" href="#musicas">Músicas</a></li>
     <li id="compre-link"><a class="float" class="scroll" href="#compre">Compre</a></li>
     <li id="contato-link"><a class="float" class="scroll" href="#contato">Contato</a></li>   
  </ul>
</div>  <!-- END header -->
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    font: 28px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:90px;
}
#header ul {
    width: 65%;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    top:40%;
}
#header li {
    display:inline;
    padding-left:8%;
}
#header li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#cebc85;
}
#header li a:hover {
    color:#cebc85;
    font-weight:400;
}

/* Float */
.float {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.float:hover, .float:focus, .float:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LBJZV/**

Comment: Editei sua pergunta adicionando os códigos, assim se o link externo se tornar indisponível, sua pergunta ainda terá validade e poderá ajudar outros usuários.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percebi o problema **somente no Internet Explorer e Safari**. Seu código parece funcionar no Chrome e Firefox, porém existem alguns problemas conforme abaixo:

Para definir duas classes para um elemento, você está fazendo

```
<a class="float" class="scroll" href="#agenda">Agenda</a>
```

Altere para

```
<a class="float scroll" href="#agenda">Agenda</a>
```

O efeito indesejado ocorre, por que a largura do `li` não está definida e a largura muda conforme o texto, não há como evitar isto sem definir uma largura. Para retirar este efeito indesejado, sugiro as seguintes alterações:

Altere seu **CSS** de

```
#header ul {
    width: 65%;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    top:40%;
}

#header li {
    display:inline;
    padding-left:8%;
}
```

Para

```
 #header ul {
    width: 80%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    top:40%;
}

#header ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left:8%;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LBJZV/9/**

Comment: colocar o "float scroll" funcionou perfeitamente. Mas o display:inline-block não funcionou, continua movendo os textos do lado.

Comment: @JefSilva qual navegador e versão está utilizando? Teste este código http://jsfiddle.net/LBJZV/7/

Comment: estou utilizando o Safari e o Chrome no Mac. Testei esse código e continua, se tu trocar o font-weight do hover para 600, vai notar mais o Jitter.

Comment: @JefSilva editei a resposta com uma sugestão, porém usando `display:table` no `ul`, não sei se resolve seu problema.

Comment: funcionou!! Muito obrigado! Só tive que fazer algumas alterações no #header ul, mas ficou 100% agora. :D

Comment: @JefSilva, seria interessante marcar a resposta como aceita para finalizar a pergunta